# Classpath is getting interpreted as a string instead of actual classpath in SpringBoot project

Tags: classpath

I am trying to pass a system property through VM arguments of run configurations in IntelliJ like -Djava.secuirty.auth.login.config=classpath:jaas/jaas.config to my Spring Boot application. But when I am starting up the application spring is not considering it as a classpath(relative path) and trying to find an actual directory location named classpath in my system.

However there is another Spring project where I am passing the same command and spring is able to identify the classpath prefix there. Can anyone point out what I may be missing?

When I pass the absolute path of the file spring is able to find the file however when I use classpath it is not able to interpret it as classpath

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.